# Restrict sender and recipient with postfix

Tags: postfix, restrictions

Sorry for doubling the questions about this topic but there are so many and some are very confusing, some are still "old" format and some others does not match my case.

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = allowed
allowed = permit

smtpd_sender_restrictions =
        check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/restricted_senders,
        reject

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
        permit_mynetworks,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_domains,
        reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rhsbl_helo dbl.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rhsbl_sender dbl.spamhaus.org
```

I have this code working but I can still send mails to root@thisserver.net
(some random users)

```
Apr  4 13:40:46 mail-server postfix/local[22937]: 0C1C5160030: to=<root@thisserver.net>, relay=local, delay=0.23, delays=0.23/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: /usr/bin/procmail)
```

And "user@thisserver.net"

```
Apr  4 13:41:42 mail-server postfix/smtpd[22931]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-vk0-f52.google.com[209.85.213.52]: 550 5.1.1 <user@thisserver.net>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; from=<someuser@randomserver.com> to=<user@thisserver.net> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-vk0-f52.google.com>
Apr  4 13:41:42 mail-server postfix/smtpd[22931]: disconnect from mail-vk0-f52.google.com[209.85.213.52]
```

*What I would like to achieve is that only 1 user of this email server (info@thisserver.net) is able to send and receive emails, any other must be rejected almost instantly.
And this user can only receive mails from a few users and "recipient_domains"*

**restricted_senders:**

```
info@thisserver.net allowed
```

**recipient_domains:**

```
info@google.com allowed
user35@server.com allowed
thisserveronly.net allowed
```

Please can anybody advice if my configuration's got errors or if I just miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = 
    permit_mynetworks, 
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unauth_destination

smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/restricted_senders, 
    reject

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_domains
```

Allows me to send to thisserver.net from the accounts in restricted_senders and "rcpt to:" will deliver only to "recipient_domain", inside there is info@thisserver.net  Only.

Of course, I also added the TXT record on the dns for SPF.